# Swift 4 Codable array with dictionary has value of String and Array

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, codable

```
struct ProductDetails:Codable {
    var custom_attributes:[CustomAttributesData]
    struct CustomAttributesData:Codable {
        var attribute_code:String
        var value:String
    }
}
```

I have an `Array` of custom_attributes has `dictionary` with elements of attribute_code as `String` & value as `String`, but some value datatype's are in `Array`, due to `Array` I am not able to parse using `codable`, help me out, Thanks in advance

```
"custom_attributes": [
    {
        "attribute_code": "image",
        "value": "/6/_/6.jpg"
    },
    {
        "attribute_code": "small_image",
        "value": "/6/_/6.jpg"
    }
    {
        "attribute_code": "news_to_date",
        "value": "2017-09-30 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "attribute_code": "category_ids",
        "value": [
            "2",
            "120"
        ]
    },
    {
        "attribute_code": "options_container",
        "value": "container2"
    }
]
```

I have added `json` above.

Comment: Post the raw JSON, not a screenshot

Comment: You have to write a custom initializer `init(from decoder: Decoder)`. Add a `do - catch` block and decode `String`. If it throws an error decode `[String]`

Comment: @CodeDifferent i have changed to json.

Comment: @vadian i have done the same, so that in catch block i am getting an error 'The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.'

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a custom initializer which distinguishes between `String` and `[String]`.

This code declares `value` as `[String]` and converts a single string to an array

```
struct ProductDetails : Decodable {
    let custom_attributes : [CustomAttributesData]

    struct CustomAttributesData : Decodable {

        private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case attributeCode = "attribute_code", value
        }

        let attributeCode : String
        let value : [String]

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            attributeCode = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .attributeCode)
            do {
                let string = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .value)
                value = [string]
            } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
                value = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .value)
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use two separate properties `stringValue` and `arrayValue`